# Problemas al guardar datos en un documento desde C#

Tags: c#, base-de-datos, windows-forms, excel

¡Hola a todos!
He estado teniendo un problema al trabajar con las librerías de **SpreadSheetLight**. Al intentar guardar unos datos en una hoja de Excel me sale el siguiente error:

> La matriz de entrada es más larga que el número de columnas en esta tabla.

La tabla en la que guardaré la información lucirá algo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Qué he intentado?
He intentado guardar solo un dato, he intentado eliminando el "while", he intentado creando otro documento de excel y hasta he intentado cambiar la posición de Rows por las Columnas y Viceversa.

Les dejo el código que tengo:
(Uso Forms .NET Framework y trabajo con Visual Studio 2019)

```
    private void añadirRegistro(string name, string ape, string email, string user, string especialidad, string genero, string titulo, string pass) {
        var Opcion = DialogResult.Cancel;
        string pathFile;
        int errorES;
        do {
            try
            {
                SLDocument oSLDocument = new SLDocument();
                pathFile = '"'+AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "data\\registros.xlsx" + '"';
                System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable(pathFile,"Hoja1");
                int iRow = 3;
                while (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(oSLDocument.GetCellValueAsString(iRow, 1)))
                {
                    iRow++;
                }

                //registros , rows
                dt.Rows.Add(user, name, ape, email, especialidad, genero, titulo, pass);

                oSLDocument.ImportDataTable(iRow, 1, dt, false);
                oSLDocument.Save();
                errorES = 0;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Opcion = MessageBox.Show("Ha ocurrido un error al intentar registrar sus datos:\n "+ex.Message, "ERROR:01", MessageBoxButtons.RetryCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                errorES = 1;
            }
        } while (Opcion == DialogResult.Retry);

        //Solo si no da errores lo muestra.
        if (errorES == 0){
            MessageBox.Show("¡Registro completado!", "Ëxito", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }

    }
```

Espero me puedan ayudar, soy nuevo y lo necesito para un proyecto de mi colegio.
Gracias.